# how to extract data from namedtuple in file handling in python

Tags: python, file, namedtuple

Having trouble extracting data from namedtuple in file handling in python.
It shows property object at --- location

```
from collections import namedtuple

filename=input("Enter name of file ")
Data=namedtuple('Data',['name','id','balance'])

def write():
    file=open(filename,'a')
    name=input("Enter name ")
    idee=input("Enter ID ")
    bal=input("Enter balance ")   
    data=Data(name,idee,bal)
    file.write(str(data))
    file.close()

def read():
    file=open(filename,'r')
    for line in file:
        print(Data.name,"\t",Data.id,"\t",Data.balance,"\n")

write()
write()
read()
```

What should I do to extract data in `data.name`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you write the data to the file it is just only a string and you can get only string when you read it.

```
from collections import namedtuple
import pickle
filename=input("Enter name of file ")
Data=namedtuple('Data',['name','id','balance'])

def write():

    name=input("Enter name ")
    idee=input("Enter ID ")
    bal=input("Enter balance ")   
    data=Data(name,idee,bal)
    with open(filename,'ab') as f:
       pickle.dump(data,f)

def read():
    with open(filename,'rb') as f:
       while True:
        try:
         data=pickle.load(f)
         print(data.name,"\t",data.id,"\t",data.balance,"\n")
        except:
            break

write()
write()
read()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just do:

```
print("%s\t%d\t%s\n" % line)
```

to print the contents of the namedtuple. The official documentation may not be very obvious, but [here is a good tutorial to understand named tuples](https://pymotw.com/2/collections/namedtuple.html#namedtuple)